# Zero result from a positive integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic

**Bug introduced in 12.2 or earlier and persisting through 13.0.1.**

---

How to calculate the following symbolic integral in MMA?

Every variable is real. Although the **integrand is always positive**, MMA (mine is V12.2) just gives zero as far as I've tried.
It is wrong for sure. Note also that if we set `b=0` in the first place, it can give the corresponding correct finite result.

```
f = 1/((-(a - I b) + (x + I c)^2) (-(a + I b) + (x - I c)^2));
Integrate[f, {x, -∞, ∞}]
Integrate[f, {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0 && b ∈ Reals]
```

**Edit**

Taking into account several comments under this question (and anwers as well) it is plausible rewriting the integral to another form where the system returns  manifestly wrong results justifying the [`bugs`**`x`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) tag.  Namely the integral can be recast to the form `positive constant` times `non-zero integral`, e.g.

```
Integrate[ 1/(4 p^2 (q + z)^2 + (-1 - p^2 + z^2)^2), {z, -∞, ∞}, 
           Assumptions -> p > 0 && q == Sqrt[p^2 + 1]]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

while setting for `p` a specific value, e.g. `p = 1;`

```
Integrate[ 1/(4 p^2 (q + z)^2 + (-1 - p^2 + z^2)^2), {z, -∞, ∞}, 
           Assumptions -> q == Sqrt[p^2 + 1]]
```

the system returns correctly a warning that the integral does not converge.

Comment: Mathematica is right in view of `r = Simplify[f, Assumptions -> {a, b, c} \[Element] Reals && x > 0];s=Simplify[f,Assumptions->Assumptions->{a,b,c}\[Element]Reals&&x>0&&x<0];r-s` which results in `0`.

Comment: @user64494 The integrand is positive....

Comment: xiaohuamao (@ does not work): The integrand is complex-valued, not positive. Master your math.

Comment: @user64494 The integrand is in the form $a\times a^*$, which is positive.

Comment: xiaohuamao (@ does not work):  You are right, Mathematica too.

Comment: @Artes & xiaohuamao: As is explained in my answer, this is not any bug, since no incorrect answer is produced, but a weakness, since a useless answer is produced.

Comment: @user64494 Your "answer" is unrelated to the problem at hand.  The question concerns `Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0 && Element[b, Reals]` while you are  playing with `Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && c \[Element] Reals]`. Nonetheless I have looked at the problem more thoroughly and It contains a bug.   This integral can be rewritten as `Integrate[1/((q + 2 p z)^2 + (-1 - p^2 + z^2)^2), {z, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, Assumptions -> p > 0 && q \[Element] Reals]`  and it produces `0` under **unrelated** conditions.  The system should not return anything unrelated, the input  itself would be ok.

Comment: This should be calassified as a bug since at a critical point the system fails. I can agree this is a bug in a weaker sense, however the answer is wrong even though logically the answer is right. A really nice question pointing out **wrong** behaviour, (+1) upvoted earlier, if possible I would upvote (+5).

Comment: @Artes:"the answer is wrong even though logically the answer is right" is empty words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split the integration range from -Infinity to 0 and from 0 to Infinity.
Add the two Rootsums and convert the result to radicals, then help Mathematica simplify the result. You will find

```
NIntegrate[1/(a^2 + b^2 + 4*b*c*x + 2*a*(c^2 - x^2) + (c^2 + x^2)^2),
{x, -100, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

equals

```
(2*Pi*c)/(4*c^2*(a + c^2) - b^2)
```

if the conditions

```
c > Sqrt[Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] - a]/Sqrt[2] for a,b > 0
```

or

```
0 < b < 2*c*Sqrt[a + c^2] for a,c > 0
```

or

```
a > (b^2 - 4*c^4)/(4*c^2) for b,c > 0
```

are met. I hope I got the conditions right...

Edit:

actually one condition is enough:

```
b < 2*c*Sqrt[a + c^2]
```

With it the Log replacements are correct and you get:

```
Simplify[Simplify[Together[
ToRadicals[
Integrate[1/(a^2 + b^2 + 4*b*c*x + 2*a*(c^2 - x^2) + 
                (c^2 + x^2)^2), {x, -Infinity, 0}] + 
Integrate[1/(a^2 + b^2 + 4*b*c*x + 2*a*(c^2 - x^2) + 
(c^2 + x^2)^2),{x, 0, Infinity}]]]] /. 
    {Log[-Sqrt[a - I*b] - I*c] -> 
     Log[Sqrt[a - I*b] + I*c] - I*Pi, 
     Log[-Sqrt[a + I*b] + I*c] -> 
     Log[Sqrt[a + I*b] - I*c] + I*Pi, 
     Log[-Sqrt[a - I*b] + I*c] -> 
     Log[Sqrt[a - I*b] - I*c] + I*Pi, 
     Log[-Sqrt[a + I*b] - I*c] -> 
     Log[Sqrt[a + I*b] + I*c] - I*Pi}]
(* (2*c*Pi)/(-b^2 + 4*c^2*(a + c^2)) *)
```

Tested with plots (following code was edited + condition for range of c added):

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 3}]; 
b = RandomReal[{-3, 3}]; 
c = RandomReal[{Sqrt[Abs[b]/2], 3}]; 
p1 = LogPlot[{NIntegrate[1/(a^2 + b^2 + 4*b*c*x + 
 2*a*(c^2 - x^2) + (c^2 + x^2)^2), {x, -100, 100}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 200], (2*Pi*c)/(4*c^2*(a + c^2) - b^2)}, 
 {a, (b^2 - 4*c^4)/(4*c^2), 8}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}]; 
p2 = LogPlot[{NIntegrate[1/(a^2 + b^2 + 4*b*c*x + 
 2*a*(c^2 - x^2) + (c^2 + x^2)^2), {x, -100, 100}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 200], (2*Pi*c)/(4*c^2*(a + c^2) - b^2)}, 
 {b, -2*c*Sqrt[a + c^2], 2*c*Sqrt[a + c^2]}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Dashed}]; 
p3 = LogPlot[{NIntegrate[1/(a^2 + b^2 + 4*b*c*x + 
 2*a*(c^2 - x^2) + (c^2 + x^2)^2), {x, -100, 100}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 200], (2*Pi*c)/(4*c^2*(a + c^2) - b^2)}, 
 {c, Sqrt[Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] - a]/Sqrt[2], 8}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]; 
{a, b, c}
Show[p1, p2, p3, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate "

Split the integration range from -Infinity to 0 and from 0 to Infinity. Add the two Rootsums and convert the result to radicals, then help Mathematica simplify the result"?  In other case, all that is built on the sand.

Comment: @user64494 Well, over the whole range the integral reports zero for some reason. the split gives two rootsums which then have to be added, apply ToRadicals[] and simplify

Comment: Sorry, I am waiting a Mathematica code, not empty words.

Comment: @user64494 don't pretend you have never used Mathematica before. I wrote everything necessary to test the calculation and won't expand on this more

Comment: `Integrate[f, {x, -\[Infinity], 0}, 
   Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0 && Element[b, Reals]] + 
  Integrate[f, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
   Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0 && Element[b, Reals]] ` results in `ConditionalExpression[
 RootSum[a^2 + b^2 + 2*a*c^2 + c^4 - 4*b*c*#1 - 2*a*#1^2 + 
      2*c^2*#1^2 + #1^4 & , 
    Log[-#1]/(b*c + a*#1 - c^2*#1 - #1^3) & ]/4 - 
  RootSum[a^2 + b^2 + 2*a*c^2 + c^4 + 4*b*c*#1 - 2*a*#1^2 + 
      2*c^2*#1^2 + #1^4 & , 
    Log[-#1]/(b*c - a*#1 + c^2*#1 + #1^3) & ]/4,  huge condition
 ]`, This huge condition is unclear to me.

Comment: I think this is your duty to explain `(2*Pi*c)/(4*c^2*(a + c^2) - b^2)` and `c > Sqrt[Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] - a]/Sqrt[2] for a,b > 0` and the rest.

Comment: The crucial step `{Log[-Sqrt[a - I*b] - I*c] -> 
     Log[Sqrt[a - I*b] + I*c] - I*Pi, 
     Log[-Sqrt[a + I*b] + I*c] -> 
     Log[Sqrt[a + I*b] - I*c] + I*Pi, 
     Log[-Sqrt[a - I*b] + I*c] -> 
     Log[Sqrt[a - I*b] - I*c] + I*Pi, 
     Log[-Sqrt[a + I*b] - I*c] -> 
     Log[Sqrt[a + I*b] + I*c] - I*Pi}` is done by hand and ungrounded.

Comment: Cannot reproduce `Simplify[Simplify[
   Together[
    ToRadicals[
     Integrate[
       1/(a^2 + b^2 + 4*b*c*x + 
          2*a*(c^2 - x^2) + (c^2 + x^2)^2), {x, -Infinity, 0}] + 
      Integrate[
       1/(a^2 + b^2 + 4*b*c*x + 2*a*(c^2 - x^2) + (c^2 + x^2)^2), {x, 
        0, Infinity}]]]] /. {Log[-Sqrt[a - I*b] - I*c] -> 
    Log[Sqrt[a - I*b] + I*c] - I*Pi, 
   Log[-Sqrt[a + I*b] + I*c] -> Log[Sqrt[a + I*b] - I*c] + I*Pi, 
   Log[-Sqrt[a - I*b] + I*c] -> Log[Sqrt[a - I*b] - I*c] + I*Pi, 
   Log[-Sqrt[a + I*b] - I*c] -> Log[Sqrt[a + I*b] + I*c] - I*Pi}]`, which runs

Comment: without any response on my comp for a long time.

Comment: "13.0.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" It takes 29 secs

Comment: No response on my comp during more than a half hour.

Comment: At last, I obtain `ConditionalExpression[(2*c*Pi)/(-b^2 + 4*c^2*(a + c^2)), a huge condition ]`. Therefore, your output in the question `(* (2*c*Pi)/(-b^2 + 4*c^2*(a + c^2)) *)` does not correspond to reality.

Comment: @Andreas I would add that, for me, trying `Integrate[f, {x, -Infinity, 0, Infinity},...]` is a standard move when `Integrate` misbehaves. I'm not sure why putting a waypoint on the integration path sometimes helps, but I think it changes how `Integrate` deals with branch points.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit2** corrected error in cc2 and int2

Now for some paramter values int1 is valid, for other int2 and for some int1 yield wrong complex solutions. See Manipulate...

**Edit**
Of course straightforward integration should give the right result. But it does not. **This is a bug** !

Nevertheless found a way to elict the right result, but still some partly wrong answer in conditions remain.

Split the integrand with Apart.

```
f[a_, b_, c_] = 
    1/((-(a - I b) + (x + I c)^2) (-(a + I b) + (x - I c)^2));

fap = f[a, b, c] // Apart

(*   (-I b + 4 c^2 + 2 I c x)/(
 2 (b^2 - 4 a c^2 - 4 c^4) (-a - I b - c^2 - 2 I c x + x^2)) + (
 I b + 4 c^2 - 2 I c x)/(
 2 (b^2 - 4 a c^2 - 4 c^4) (-a + I b - c^2 + 2 I c x + x^2))   *)

cc1 = ComplexExpand[fap[[1]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // 
  Simplify[#, Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0 && Element[b, Reals]] &

(*   (I (b + 4 I c^2 - 2 c x))/(2 (b^2 - 4 c^2 (a + c^2)) (a + 
   I b + (c + I x)^2))   *)

cc2 = ComplexExpand[fap[[2]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // 
  Simplify[#, Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0 && Element[b, Reals]] &

    (*   (b - 4 I c^2 - 
 2 c x)/(2 (b^2 - 4 c^2 (a + c^2)) (I a + b + I (c - I x)^2))   *)


int1[a_, b_, c_] = 
 Integrate[cc1, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
   Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0 && Element[b, Reals]] // 
  FullSimplify[#, 
    Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0 && b \[Element] Reals] &

(*   ConditionalExpression[-((2 c \[Pi])/(
  b^2 - 4 c^2 (a + c^2))), -c - Im[Sqrt[a + I b]] < 
   0 && -c + Im[Sqrt[a + I b]] < 
   0 && (b <= 2 c^2 || 4 c^2 (a + c^2) > b^2)]   *)
int2[a_, b_, c_] = 
 Integrate[cc2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
   Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0 && Element[b, Reals]] // 
  FullSimplify[#, 
    Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0 && b \[Element] Reals] &

(*   ConditionalExpression[((b + 2 (Sqrt[a - I b] - I c) c) \[Pi])/(
 2 Sqrt[a - I b] (b^2 - 4 c^2 (a + c^2))), 
 b > 2 c^2 && 4 c^2 (a + c^2) < b^2]   *)

int1[1, 1, 1] // N
(*   0.897598   *)

nint[a_, b_, c_] := 
   NIntegrate[f[a, b, c], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

nint[1, 1, 1]
(*   0.897598\[VeryThinSpace]+ 0. I   *)

Manipulate[{int1[a, b, c] // N, int2[a, b, c] // N, 
  nint[a, b, c] // Chop}, {{a, 1}, 0, 5}, {{b, 1}, -5, 5}, {{c, 1}, 0,
   6}]

$Version  (*   "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (December 9, 2010)"   *)
```

**Edit3**

Show, where int1 and int2 are defined.

```
RegionPlot3D[-c - Im[Sqrt[a + I b]] < 0 && -c + Im[Sqrt[a + I b]] < 
   0 && (b <= 2 c^2 || 4 c^2 (a + c^2) > b^2), {a, 0, 10}, {b, -5, 
  5}, {c, 0, 10}]

RegionPlot3D[
 b > 2 c^2 && 4 c^2 (a + c^2) < b^2, {a, 0, 10}, {b, -5, 5}, {c, 0, 
  10}]
```

Comment: -1. Unfortunately, `Im[Root[a^2 + b^2 + 2 a c^2 + c^4 + 
       4 b c #1 + (-2 a + 2 c^2) #1^2 + #1^4 &, 3]] > 0 && 
  Im[Root[a^2 + b^2 + 2 a c^2 + c^4 + 
       4 b c #1 + (-2 a + 2 c^2) #1^2 + #1^4 &, 2]] > 0 && 
  Im[Root[a^2 + b^2 + 2 a c^2 + c^4 + 
       4 b c #1 + (-2 a + 2 c^2) #1^2 + #1^4 &, 4]] > 0 && 
  Im[Root[a^2 + b^2 + 2 a c^2 + c^4 + 
       4 b c #1 + (-2 a + 2 c^2) #1^2 + #1^4 &, 1]] > 0 /. {a -> 1, 
  b -> 1, c -> 1}` produces `False`. Therefore, `int2[1, 1, 1] // N` is wrong.

Comment: Also cannot execute `f[a_, b_, c_] = 
  1/((-(a - I b) + (x + I c)^2) (-(a + I b) + (x - I c)^2));

fap = f[a, b, c] // Apart;
cc1 = ComplexExpand[fap[[1]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // 
  Simplify[#, Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0 && Element[b, Reals]] &`, obtaining "Tag Times in (1/((-a-I\b+(-I c+x)^2)\(-a+I\b+(I c+x)^2)))[a_,b_,c_] \
is Protected".

Comment: `ClearAll` helps for the above. But executing `int1[a_, b_, c_] = 
 Integrate[cc1, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
   Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0 && Element[b, Reals]] // 
  FullSimplify[#, 
    Assumptions -> c > 0 && a > 0 && b \[Element] Reals] &`, I obtain "Integral of (I (b+4 I c^2-2 c x))/(2 (b^2-4 c^2 (a+c^2)) (a+I b+(c+I x)^2)) does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]" and the returned input in version 13 on Windows 10.

Comment: Please present the executed code as nb. file  and/or its pdf file  through Dropbox or other tool. In opposite case your answer is empty words (Version 8 is rare at the present.). Hope I am clear. Regard.

Comment: You wrote "This is a bug !". This is not a bug, but a weakness. Version 13 on Windows produces `0` under an impossible condition.

Comment: 1. Your `int1` is part of the integral. Why is it equal to the numerical integration of the full integrand? Or did I misunderstand? 2. `int1` and `int2` do not converge with V12.2 either symbolically or numerically. Probably something wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: "1. Your int1 is part of the integral. Why is it equal to the numerical integration of the full integrand?"  As you see, int1 and int2 come together with conditions for the parameters b,c,m. for certain conditions, where int1 gives same result as numerical integration, int2 is not defined, means, does not satisfy conditions for it. And vice verse for int2 and int1. See edit3 to my answer. to 2. can't say anything to V12.2, do not use it.

Comment: Since `fap[[1]]` is just the complex conjugate of `fap[[2]]`, I don't see mathematically how 1) `int1` and `int2` could be mutually exclusive 2) `int1` could give the correct full result (should be half). Let me know if I misunderstood anything. BTW, please @ me when you reply.

Answer (score -6):

Mathematica is right. Indeed, the command

```
Integrate[ 1/((-(a - I b) + (x + I c)^2) (-(a + I b) + (x - I c)^2)),
 {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && c \[Element] Reals]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[0,  Im[Root[a^2 + b^2 + 2*a*c^2 + c^4 + 4*b*c*#1 +  (-2*a + 2*c^2)*#1^2 + #1^4 & , 1]] > 0 &&  Im[Root[a^2 + b^2 + 2*a*c^2 + c^4 + 4*b*c*#1 +  (-2*a + 2*c^2)*#1^2 + #1^4 & , 2]] > 0 &&  Im[Root[a^2 + b^2 + 2*a*c^2 + c^4 + 4*b*c*#1 +  (-2*a + 2*c^2)*#1^2 + #1^4 & , 3]] > 0 &&  Im[Root[a^2 + b^2 + 2*a*c^2 + c^4 + 4*b*c*#1 +  (-2*a + 2*c^2)*#1^2 + #1^4 & , 4]] > 0]`

results in `0`, but the condition is impossible: all the four roots of a polynomial of fourth degree with real coefficients cannot have the positive imaginary parts.

PS. So Mathematica fails here, not producing a constructive answer. However, its answer is not wrong: under  the certain impossible condition the integral equals `0`.

Edit. Skip of key-board: "imaginary" is added.

Comment: Please explain the down-vote. What is incorrect in my answer?

Comment: –1: your answer is obviously wrong. A simple `With[{a = 0.2, b = 0.3, c = 0.4}, LogPlot[1/((-(a - I b) + (x + I c)^2) (-(a + I b) + (x - I c)^2)), {x, -10, 10}]]` shows that the integrand is positive-definite and therefore the integral must be positive for these specific values of $a, b, c$ (which I've picked at random).

Comment: @Roman: Master your math. The Mathematica answer claims that the integral equals zero under the certain impossible condition. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @Roman: Here is a simpler example of such true proposition: if $2+2=5$, then $2+3=6$.

Comment: Technically you are right; in practice, this answer is useless because wrong for all values of $a,b,c$. What the OP wants is an expression that gives the integral in question, and not a counter-factual but "technically correct" mathematical subtlety. "The integral is zero whenever your parameters satisfy a non-satisfiable condition" is not a useful answer; calling it "mathematically correct" does not help in practice.

Comment: @Roman: You open an opened door, repeating a part of my answer in other words.

Comment: @Roman has hit the heart of the matter: mathematics as practiced by most of us is **useful**. Sophistry is useless.