# Finding local minimum of a 2D potential

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I tried to find a local minimum point of a 2D potential `U[\[Chi],\[CurlyPhi]]` with both `FindMinimum` and `NMinimize` function. But both gave me similar error, something like:

```
FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value U[0.3,0.1] is not a real number at {\[Chi],\[CurlyPhi]} = {0.3,0.1}.
```

I also tried to put my potential like `U[\[Chi]_?NumericQ, \[CurlyPhi]_?NumericQ]`, but it wouldn't work as well. Ideally, the local minimum should be either around `{\[Chi]=0.9,\[CurlyPhi]=0.2}`, or does not exist when both `\[Chi]>0 && \[CurlyPhi]>0`.

[image: The shape of the potential]

I'll attach my code below and I'd appreciate if someone could take a look at it!

```
\[Xi] = 79;
M = 4.2*10^-5;
Subscript[M, pl] = 1;
Subscript[\[Lambda], min] = 4.10614*10^-6;
\[Lambda][\[CurlyPhi]_] = 
  Subscript[\[Lambda], min] + 
   0.5/(16*\[Pi]^2)^2*(Log[\[CurlyPhi]/(0.15*Subscript[M, pl])])^2;
U[\[Chi]_?NumericQ, \[CurlyPhi]_?NumericQ] = \[Lambda][\[CurlyPhi]]/
    4 \[CurlyPhi]^4 Exp[-2 Sqrt[2/3] \[Chi]/Subscript[M, pl]] + 
   3/4*(Subscript[M, pl]*M)^2*
    Exp[-2 Sqrt[2/3] \[Chi]/Subscript[M, 
      pl]] (Exp[Sqrt[2/3] \[Chi]/Subscript[M, pl]] - 1 - 
      1/Subscript[M, pl]^2 \[Xi]*\[CurlyPhi]^2)^2;

NMinimize[{U[\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi]] >= 0 && 0 <= \[Chi] <= 1 &&
   0 <= \[CurlyPhi] <= 0.2}, {\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi]}, 
 MaxIterations -> 500]
```

Comment: The result of `Plot3D[U[\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi]], {\[Chi], 0, 1}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 0.2}, 
 PlotRange -> All]` clearly shows no local extremum.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've also attached the figure in my question. You could have a look at the point where the blue line ends, does that look like a local minimum?

Comment: See [that](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzzavwn6724n3si/plot3d%2017.05.2022.pdf?dl=0). In fact, the plot is almost flat and this implies  artefacts.

Comment: The objective function must evaluate to a numeric value. `U[\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi]] >= 0` will evaluate to `True` or `False`. Your argument to `NMinimize` should be `{U[\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi]], U[\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi]] >= 0 && 0 <= \[Chi] <= 1 && 0 <= \[CurlyPhi] <= 0.2}`

Comment: @Jerry , you seem to be not very interessted about an answer to your question.  Getting a good answer, but giving no upvote or accept or even a comment is not very polite.

Comment: @Akku14 Sorry for not replying earlier. I definitely saw your answer, but I was overloaded with an exam, so I didn't reproduce the result you showed - which I would do later today! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you very much for the suggestion! Now I notice my syntax error!

Comment: Ok. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

There is a local minimum. Rationalize parameter and first search for minimum curve with respect to chi. This can be achieved by intermediate substitution of exp term.

```
\[Xi] = 79;
M = 4.2*10^-5 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
Subscript[M, pl] = 1;
Subscript[\[Lambda], min] = 4.10614*10^-6 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
\[Lambda][\[CurlyPhi]_] = 
  Subscript[\[Lambda], min] + 
    0.5/(16*\[Pi]^2)^2*(Log[\[CurlyPhi]/(0.15*Subscript[M, pl])])^2 //
    Rationalize[#, 0] &;
U[\[Chi]_, \[CurlyPhi]_] = \[Lambda][\[CurlyPhi]]/
     4 \[CurlyPhi]^4 Exp[-2 Sqrt[2/3] \[Chi]/Subscript[M, pl]] + 
   3/4*(Subscript[M, pl]*M)^2*
    Exp[-2 Sqrt[2/3] \[Chi]/
       Subscript[M, pl]] (Exp[Sqrt[2/3] \[Chi]/Subscript[M, pl]] - 
       1 - 1/Subscript[M, pl]^2 \[Xi]*\[CurlyPhi]^2)^2 // Together

sol = First@Solve[E^(Sqrt[2/3] \[Chi]) == k, \[Chi]]

kmin[\[CurlyPhi]_] = 
 k /. Minimize[U[\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi]] /. sol, k][[2]] // Simplify

pl = Plot3D[
   U[\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi]], {\[Chi], 1/2, 1}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 1/5}, 
   PlotRange -> {5 10^-11, 10^-10}, PlotPoints -> 100];

pp = ParametricPlot3D[{Sqrt[3/2] Log[kmin[\[CurlyPhi]]], \[CurlyPhi], 
    U[Sqrt[3/2] Log[kmin[\[CurlyPhi]]], \[CurlyPhi]]}, {\[CurlyPhi], 
    0, .13}, AspectRatio -> 1.3, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.01], Red}];

Show[pl, pp]
```

[image]

```
min = Minimize[{U[Sqrt[3/2] Log[kmin[\[CurlyPhi]]], \[CurlyPhi]], 
    1/10 < \[CurlyPhi]}, \[CurlyPhi]] // FullSimplify

(*   {(1323 (2779978537932271 + 
      13574950000000000 Log[
        20/3 Root[{2779978537932271 + 
             6787475000000000 Log[(20 #1)/
               3] (1 + 2 Log[(20 #1)/3] + 79 #1^2) &, 
           0.112590521985889151866}]]^2) Root[{2779978537932271 + 
        6787475000000000 Log[(20 #1)/
          3] (1 + 2 Log[(20 #1)/3] + 79 #1^2) &, 
      0.112590521985889151866}]^4)/(200000000000 (17914204609119 + 
      2830444328240802 Root[{2779978537932271 + 
           6787475000000000 Log[(20 #1)/
             3] (1 + 2 Log[(20 #1)/3] + 79 #1^2) &, 
         0.112590521985889151866}]^2 + 
      2 (62851221827586517 + 
         33937375000000000 Log[
           20/3 Root[{2779978537932271 + 
                6787475000000000 Log[(20 #1)/
                  3] (1 + 2 Log[(20 #1)/3] + 79 #1^2) &, 
              0.112590521985889151866}]]^2) Root[{2779978537932271 + 
           6787475000000000 Log[(20 #1)/
             3] (1 + 2 Log[(20 #1)/3] + 79 #1^2) &, 
         0.112590521985889151866}]^4)), {\[CurlyPhi] -> 
   Root[{2779978537932271 + 
       6787475000000000 Log[(20 #1)/
         3] (1 + 2 Log[(20 #1)/3] + 79 #1^2) &, 
     0.112590521985889151866}]}}   *)

Sqrt[3/2] Log[kmin[\[CurlyPhi]]] /. min[[2]] // N

(*   0.902127   *)

Plot[U[Sqrt[3/2]
    Log[kmin[\[CurlyPhi]]], \[CurlyPhi]], {\[CurlyPhi], .10, .12}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.03], 
   Point[{\[CurlyPhi], 
      U[Sqrt[3/2] Log[kmin[\[CurlyPhi]]], \[CurlyPhi]]} /. min[[2]]]}]
```

[image]

```
NMinimize[{U[\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi]], 
  0 <= \[Chi] <= 1 && 
   0 <= \[CurlyPhi] <= 2/10}, {\[Chi], {\[CurlyPhi], 1/10, 2/10}}, 
 MaxIterations -> 500, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

$Version   "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (December 9, 2010)"

Comment: Executing `\[Xi] = 79;
M = 4.2*10^-5 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
Subscript[M, pl] = 1;
Subscript[\[Lambda], min] = 4.10614*10^-6 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
\[Lambda][\[CurlyPhi]_] = 
  Subscript[\[Lambda], min] + ... - 
       1 - 1/Subscript[M, pl]^2 \[Xi]*\[CurlyPhi]^2)^2 // Together
sol = First@Solve[E^(Sqrt[2/3] \[Chi]) == k, \[Chi]]
kmin[\[CurlyPhi]_] = 
 k /. Minimize[U[\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi]] /. sol, k][[2]] // Simplify` on a fresh kernel, I obtain "ReplaceAll::reps: {k} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing." and

Comment: `{\[Chi] -> 
  ConditionalExpression[
   Sqrt[3/2] (2 I \[Pi] ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]] + 
      Log[k]), 
   ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]] \[Element] Integers]}` and `k /. k`.

Comment: Also I don't see any local minimum in the result of `Plot3D[U[\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi]], {\[Chi], 0, 1}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 1/5},   PlotRange -> {0, 10^-10}, PlotPoints -> 100]`

Comment: `U[Sqrt[3/2] Log[kmin[\[CurlyPhi]]], \[CurlyPhi]]` depends on `\[CurlyPhi]]`. Its local minimum at `Point[{\[CurlyPhi], 
      U[Sqrt[3/2] Log[kmin[\[CurlyPhi]]], \[CurlyPhi]]} /. min[[2]]]` may be not a local minimum of the function of two variables `U[\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi]]` at this point.

Comment: `NMinimize[{U[\[Chi], \[CurlyPhi]], 
  0 <= \[Chi] <= 1 && 
   0 <= \[CurlyPhi] <= 2/10}, {\[Chi], {\[CurlyPhi], 1/10, 2/10}}, 
 MaxIterations -> 500, WorkingPrecision -> 60] ` finds the same local minimum.

Comment: With kmin it is shown to be a minimum with respect to k (or chi) and min finds the minimum of the remaining one dimensional curve with respect to phi.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me in version 13 (see my first and second comments). You often (for example, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267023/incorrect-results-when-solving-an-ode/267034#267034) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265739/zero-result-from-a-positive-integral/265746#265746))
 present results obtained in version 8 (without executed nb files) which are not reproducible in new versions of Mathematica, in particular in version 13.
It it difficult to believe that version 8 is stronger than new versions of Mathematica.

Comment: Since you are an expert, it should be not so difficult to adopt it to version 13.

Comment: Sorry, I have nothing to discuss with you in such manner.